# Java MimeBodyPart to byte[]

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using Java 11.  I am reading emails and retrieving their attachments using `javax.mail` and would like to save the attachments byte array.

So I need to convert a `javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart` (the attachment) to a `byte[]`.

code so far:

```
private void savePDF(MimeBodyPart attachment, String invoiceNumber) {
    byte[] data = attachment.get....
}
```

**More info:**

When I try open the PDF, I do the following:

```
InputStream is = response.getStream();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
fos = new BufferedOutputStream(output);
fos.write(bytes);
```

This works perfectly when I get the bytes from a 'MultipartFile':

```
byte[] bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
```

However, if I try use the byes from a `MimeBodyPart` (email attachment), it fails:

```
byte[] data = attachment.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
```

[image]

More info:

I have also tried, but I get the same error:

```
    BASE64DecoderStream content = (BASE64DecoderStream) attachment.getContent();
    byte[] bytes = content.readAllBytes();
    bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(bytes);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, am going to test it: `byte[] data = attachment.getInputStream().readAllBytes();`

Comment: `byte[] data = attachment.getInputStream().readAllBytes();` does not work. When I try use these bytes to open the pdf, it says it is the file has been damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm a little late but for those who wondering, you can extract all bytes from MimeBodyPart using the method `readAllBytes()` with new `jakarta.mail` library as seen in the post example or like in the following method:

```java
public byte[] getAttachmentAsByteArray(MimeBodyPart attachment) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    return attachment.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
}
```